# how do I log only the id of the json from a url?

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, url

Here's my code:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json', function (error, response, body) {
console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
```

I would like to only log the "id" of every object in the json and I am at a block on how to do so. I run this with node coded in atom. You can copy paste the url in a browser to see the full json

Comment: Can you post sample output of how you want output to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
const request = require('request')
request('http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json', function(error, response, body) {
  const ids = Object.values(JSON.parse(body).products_and_categories).reduce((o, items) => o.concat(items.map(({
    id
  }) => id)), [])
  console.log(ids)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

i am considering you as beginner so i am not using map() which is much cleaner  easier to implement  ,

consider the answer as pseudo code

```
for(let i=0;i<body.products_and_categories.length;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<body.products_and_categories[i].length;j++){
        let id = body.products_and_categories[i][j]
        // whatever you want to do with id do
    }
}
```